# Safari Error: mobx-react-lite requires React with Hooks support

Tags: react-hooks, safari, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.img[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCkpZ.png)ur.com/STTwl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozyGJ.png)
When I run my project in Safari browser, the React obtained from mobx react lite becomes the browser's useAgent

I tried to print React and other projects or versions in the browser, but they didn't work